# How to group by week no and get start date and end date for the week number in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to group the result by week no and get the start date and end date for the week. I had not idea on how to do this sqlite. Could somebody help me on this.

I also really confiused the way sqlite works. Because if run the following query i get the week no as 00

```
SELECT strftime('%W','2012-01-01');
```

and week no as 01 instead of 00 for the following query

```
SELECT strftime('%W','2012-01-02');
```

Could somebody explain why the sqlite behaves like this.

Answer (score 11):

Try this out:

```
select * from t1;

+------------+
|   ADate    |
+------------+
| 2012-01-04 |
| 2012-01-10 |
| 2012-01-19 |
| 2012-01-22 |
| 2012-01-01 |
| 2012-01-01 |
+------------+

select 
    strftime('%W', aDate) WeekNumber,
    max(date(aDate, 'weekday 0', '-7 day')) WeekStart,
    max(date(aDate, 'weekday 0', '-1 day')) WeekEnd,
    count(*) as GroupedValues
from t1
group by WeekNumber;

+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| WeekNumber | WeekStart  |  WeekEnd   | WeekNumber |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|         00 | 2011-12-25 | 2011-12-31 |          2 |
|         01 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-07 |          1 |
|         02 | 2012-01-08 | 2012-01-14 |          1 |
|         03 | 2012-01-15 | 2012-01-21 |          2 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

To be honest... I don't know why 2012-01-01 is week 0 and 2012-01-02 is week 1. Sounds very weird, particularly if the week starts on sundays! :s

Comment: We are building dashboard for web and iphone. Mysql shows the correct result but sqlite is not.

Comment: As you can see from you data, 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-04 all should come under the week no 00 but the date 2012-01-04 comes under week no 01. Can you explain this!

Comment: As I told you in the answer, I just don't know. I find it a bit contradictory too.

Comment: The above answer uses Sunday as the week start day. If you change the `-7` and `-1` arguments to `-6` and `0` Mondaywill be the week start day.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this:

```
select 
    strftime('%W', aDate, 'weekday 1') WeekNumber,
    max(date(aDate, 'weekday 1')) WeekStart,
    max(date(aDate, 'weekday 1', '+6 day')) WeekEnd,
    count(*) as GroupedValues
from t1
group by WeekNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know very much late to the party, but I can explain why.  The Strftime reference used, comes from C.  The way C calculates things is frustrating.

Days run from 0 to 6, with 0 being sunday, 6 being saturday.

However Weeks run from Monday to Sunday.

From the C documentations:

```
%w  Weekday as a decimal number with Sunday as 0 (0-6)
%W  Week number with the first Monday as the first day of week one (00-53)
```

So Week 00 would be a sunday, before the first monday of the year.  If the year started on a thursday, all the days till the Monday would be week 00.  Not sure what the ISO standard is, I think it's first Thursday of the year is week 1.

It took me a while to resolve this as I had to account for weeks running from Thursday to Wednesday.

Answer (score 2):

In short, sqlite defines week of year (%W) on Monday, according to https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and its link on strftime function (http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html).

Thus, if anyone still needs to group weeks starting on Sunday, just advance a day as below:

```
SELECT strftime('%W','2012-01-01', '+1 day')
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer can be simplified a little and allow more flexibility. Note that `this_sunday` includes the day itself if that day is Sunday.

```
SELECT
   DATE(created_at, 'weekday 0') AS this_sunday,
   COUNT(*) AS rows_this_week
FROM my_table
GROUP BY this_sunday;
```

This technique is simpler than `strftime('%W', created_at)` and it's more powerful. For example if you want to aggregate weeks ending on Monday:

```
SELECT
   DATE(created_at, 'weekday 1') AS this_monday,
   COUNT(*) AS rows_this_week
FROM my_table
GROUP BY this_monday;
```

This works thanks to the [modifier](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) `'weekday N'` which moves the date to the day of week specified if it's in the future or keeps it if it's the same day.

Finally, to verify which dates are included in your week range, I recommend this method:

```
SELECT
   DATE(created_at, 'weekday 1') AS this_monday,
   MIN(DATE(created_at)) AS earliest,
   MAX(DATE(created_at)) AS latest,
   COUNT(*) AS rows_this_week
FROM my_table
GROUP BY this_monday;
```

Answer (score 0):

according to SQL Lite documentation Sunday==0 and 2012-01-01 is a sunday so its spitting out 00;

take a look at the date time functions for sqllite here

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Please note that, I am not trying to get the week day. Actually I am trying to get the Week number of the time stamp.

If your run the first query, you will get 00 as the week no and 01 for the second query instead of 00. Because both dates comes in the first week of January and should get the same result.

SELECT strftime('%W','2012-01-01');

SELECT strftime('%W','2012-01-02');

Is this bug in sqlite?

Comment: At the bottom of the page  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html  it states all the bugs and limitations of sqlite; from the looks of it the calculations will be incorrect in windows vista!! are you running Vista or windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

If the given date is the first of the week, then `DATE('2014-07-20', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')` will return '2014-07-13', which is 7 days earlier than required.

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
CASE DATE(myDate, 'weekday 0')
  WHEN DATE(myDate) THEN DATE(myDate)
  ELSE DATE(myDate, 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
END
```